# Which LEGO set is this from?

Tags: set-identification

I recently bought a second hand LEGO set which contained 1 random sealed bag from another set.
Its bag #3, the QR code on it gives number 6171968. Can anyone identify the set from the attached photo?
Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Based on

- White Plate, Modified 2 x 3 with Hole
  and
- Tan Brick, Round Corner 3 x 3 x 2 Dome Top

this would be from
[41349: Drifting Diner](https://brickset.com/sets/41349-1/Drifting-Diner)
[image]

Comment: Very much appreciated, thank you. 
Now to find out how to get the other bags in the set / whether it’s worth it!!

Comment: Hi @Richard, if an answer has helped you, please click the tick mark next to it. That tells the system (and other contributors) that the question has been answered satisfactorily and is not looking for additional answers. See more in the [help], specifically [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).